# merge array and replace values

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays.
First, lets call it array1:

```
array (size=8)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'domacin' => string 'Man City' (length=8)
      'gost' => string 'Liverpool' (length=9)
      'tip' => string '1' (length=1)
      'kvota' => string '1.8' (length=3)
      'status' => string 'Aktivan' (length=7)
  1 => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'domacin' => string 'Inter' (length=5)
      'gost' => string 'Milan' (length=5)
      'tip' => string '1' (length=1)
      'kvota' => string '2.5' (length=3)
      'status' => string 'Aktivan' (length=7)
```

And second, array2:

```
  'id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'domacin' => string 'Man City' (length=8)
  'gost' => string 'Liverpool' (length=9)
  'tip' => string '1' (length=1)
  'kvota' => string '1.8' (length=3)
  'status' => string 'Gubitan' (length=7)
```

I want to merge this two arrays but to use values from second where id from first is equal with id from second.

Expected result would be:

```
array (size=8)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'domacin' => string 'Man City' (length=8)
      'gost' => string 'Liverpool' (length=9)
      'tip' => string '1' (length=1)
      'kvota' => string '1.8' (length=3)
      'status' => string 'Gubitan' (length=7)
  1 => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'domacin' => string 'Inter' (length=5)
      'gost' => string 'Milan' (length=5)
      'tip' => string '1' (length=1)
      'kvota' => string '2.5' (length=3)
      'status' => string 'Aktivan' (length=7)
```

Check the status where index is 0. It changed from 'Aktivan'(from array1) to 'Gubitan' like we had in array2.

How to do that?

Comment: And you have tried to do this with...?

Comment: Have you tried something like... erm... `foreach` or `array_map` + callback [as shown in this dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842272/php-array-merge-two-arrays-on-same-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($firstArr as &$item) {
    if ($item['id'] == $secondArr['id']) {
        $item = $secondArr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using two foreach loops :

```
foreach( $array1 as $key1=>$element1 ){
    foreach( $array2 as $element2 ){
        if ($element1['id'] == $element2['id'])
            {
              $array1[$key1]['status'] = $element2['status'];
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use var_dump($array1); i got this:
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
       ...
      'status' => string '2' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
       ...
      'status' => string 'Aktivan' (length=7)

array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
       ...
      'status' => string '2' (length=1)

So status get id value.