# Merge array by index/key keeping all values

Tags: php, arrays

I have `n` number of arrays

```
$array1=array('usa'=>123, 'uk' => '1234', 'germany'=> '1235');
$array2=array('usa'=>123a, 'uk' => '1234', 'germany'=> '1235aa');
$array3=array('usa'=>123, 'uk' => '1234a', 'germany'=> '123a5');

$arrayn=array('usa'=>123b, 'uk' => '1234', 'germany'=> '1235');
```

I need a php code so that I can have result as follows:

```
$final_array=array(
                 'usa'=>'123,123a,123,...,123b',
                 'uk'=>'1234,1234,1234a,...,1234', 
                 'germany'=>'1235,1235aa, 123a5,...,1235'
             );
```

Can anyone help me how to do this?

Comment: the $array1 to $arrayn are not on array? Are they individual variables?

Comment: yes they are all individual variables...

Comment: Are they fixed on number or it would vary?

Comment: @user1140176 : To get some idea from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842272/php-array-merge-two-arrays-on-same-key#answer-14843843) tutorial.

Comment: @UglyEddie : It may `static` or `dynamic`. That's not necessary here. He need some logic to merge both of them. Simple.

Comment: @UglyEddie The number of arrays varies and the element inside also varies

Comment: @Ranjith, yes it would matter. Please look at the answers below. They are on the fixed (static) 3 variables only. So those answers needed modification. Simple.

Comment: @user1140176, please check my response below. It can handle $array1 to $arrayn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So use [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) to do this:

```
$array1=array('usa'=>'123', 'uk' => '1234', 'germany'=> '1235');
$array2=array('usa'=>'123a', 'uk' => '1234', 'germany'=> '1235aa');
$array3=array('usa'=>'123', 'uk' => '1234a', 'germany'=> '123a5');

$result = array_map(function($x)
{
   return join(',', $x);
}, call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', [$array1, $array2, $array3]));
```

That is: [`array_merge_recursive()`](http://php.net/array_merge_recursive) will gather all the items with corresponding key. Later [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) will use [`join()`](http://php.net/join) to transform items to delimiter-separated strings.

Note, that, since all your arrays are separated variables, you'll have to re-count all of them in parameters array for `call_user_func_array()`

Comment: What if I have to pass n number of arrays. I mean what if i dont know how many arrays are there??

Comment: Then create array, which will contain your arrays. Because if you have some set of variables and you don't know what they are (what are their names, what are their count e t.c.) - then how can you get the result? Your input conditions should be defined, you can not do it with "unknown variables"

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function, where you can pass your arrays one by one.

```
<?php
$array1=array('usa'=>'123', 'uk' => '1234', 'germany'=> '1235');
$array2=array('usa'=>'123a', 'uk' => '1234', 'germany'=> '1235aa');
$array3=array('usa'=>'123', 'uk' => '1234a', 'germany'=> '123a5');

function add_arr($arr, &$final)
{
    foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
        if(isset($final[$key])){
            $final[$key].=",".$val;
        }else{
           $final[$key]=$val;
        }
    }
}

$arr_final=array();
add_arr($array1,$arr_final);
add_arr($array2,$arr_final);
add_arr($array3,$arr_final);

print_r($arr_final);
?>
```

Here is **[DEMO](http://codepad.org/Z7NoJTVc)**

Answer (score 1):

```
function array_merge_multiple() {
    $result = array();
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        $array = $arg_list[$i];
        $keys = array_keys($array);
        foreach ($keys as $v) {
            if (isset($result[$v])) {
                $result[$v].="," . $array[$v];
            } else {
                $result[$v] = $array[$v];
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
$result=array_merge_multiple($array1,$array2,$array3,$arrayn);
```

//$result=array_merge_multiple($array1,$array2,$array3,.........,$arrayn);

```
print_r($result);
```

Comment: this will produce your expected result, your can pass "N" Number of array.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps

```
function black_magic($arrays = array()) {
$return = array();
foreach ($arrays as $array) {
    if (!$return) {
    $return = $array;
    continue;
    }

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($return[$key])) {
        $return[$key] .= ($return[$key]) ? ",$value" : $value;
    }
    else {
        $return[$key] = $value;
    }

    unset($key, $value);
    }

    unset($array);
}

return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$array1=array('usa'=>123, 'uk' => '1234', 'germany'=> '1235');

$array3=array('usa'=>1231, 'uk' => '1234a', 'germany'=> '123a5');

$result = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array3);
```

$result being the merged results