# PHP Merge (Add) Two Arrays by Same Key

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have two arrays.

```
$a = array('a' => 2, 'b' => 5, 'c' => 8);
$b = array('a' => 3, 'b' => 7, 'c' => 10);
```

I want to merge these two arrays and get following result.

```
$c = array('a' => 5, 'b' => 12, 'c' => 18);
```

What is the easiest way to archive this?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Array Merge two Arrays on same key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842272/php-array-merge-two-arrays-on-same-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, looping through the array will do the trick.

```
$a = array('a' => 2, 'b' => 5, 'c' => 8);
$b = array('a' => 3, 'b' => 7, 'c' => 10);
$c = array();
foreach($a as $index => $item) {
  if(isset($b[$index])) {
    $new_value = $a[$index] + $b[$index];
    $c[$index] = $new_value;
  }
}
```

Comment: What if the keys were not same

Comment: @uchiha Good point. But both my arrays contains last 30 days as keys.

Comment: Its just a question you need a rigid output

Comment: @Uchiha Great point. I've added an `isset` to solve this. This will merely ignore any other keys that are in `$a` but not in `$b`. This could get more complex by adding the new key to `$c`, however this doesn't fit the scenario of the question so I didn't add it.

Comment: @Uchiha Missed a bracket. I shall blame this on it being a Monday morning!

Comment: @Tommy It was monday night for me after a long day. May be that's why I could not figure out this easy method. :) I was just messing with some D3 stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```
$c = array();
foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    if (isset($b[$k])) {
        $c[$k] = $b[$k] + $v;
    }
}
```

You need to check whether keys exist in both arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this by `foreach` loop, please see the example below

```
$c = array();
$a = array('a' => 2, 'b' => 5, 'c' => 8);
$b = array('a' => 3, 'b' => 7, 'c' => 10);
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    $tmp_value = $a[$key] + $b[$key];
    $c[$key] = $tmp_value;
}
print_r($c);
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `foreach` as

```
foreach($b as $key => $value){
    if(in_array($key,array_keys($a)))
        $result[$key] = $a[$key]+$value;

}
```