# PHP - Map two Arrays based on Key

Tags: php, arrays, explode, array-merge

**User Array**

```
print_R($user_array);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [SKILL_NAME] => Application Software
            [EXPERIENCE_BAND] => 15+
            [SITE_STATUS] => Onsite
            [NO_OF_RESOURCE] => 1
            [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 16
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [SKILL_NAME] => Application Software
            [EXPERIENCE_BAND] => 2-4
            [SITE_STATUS] => Onsite
            [NO_OF_RESOURCE] => 1
            [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 96
        )

)
```

**Value Array**

```
print_R($value_array);
Array
(
    [RATE_PER_HOUR] => 80,50
    [MARKUP_PERCENT] => 5,10
    [TOTAL_COST] => 8064.00,880.00
)
```

Exploding Value array `RATE_PER_HOUR`

`$rate_per_hour = explode(',', $array_data['RATE_PER_HOUR']);`

ouputs below. The same goes for `MARKUP_PERCENT` and `TOTAL_COST`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 80
    [1] => 50
)
```

How could I map above two arrays so that the output is like below. Array mapping is done based on key to maintain the correct data.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [SKILL_NAME] => Application Software
            [EXPERIENCE_BAND] => 15+
            [SITE_STATUS] => Onsite
            [NO_OF_RESOURCE] => 1
            [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 16
            [RATE_PER_HOUR] => 80
            [MARKUP_PERCENT] => 5
            [TOTAL_COST] => 8064.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [SKILL_NAME] => Application Software
            [EXPERIENCE_BAND] => 2-4
            [SITE_STATUS] => Onsite
            [NO_OF_RESOURCE] => 1
            [ACTUAL_HOURS] => 96
            [RATE_PER_HOUR] => 50
            [MARKUP_PERCENT] => 10
            [TOTAL_COST] => 880.00
        )

)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Tried using array_merge, but  not sure how to go about it key based.

Comment: Can you show us your code context? Like `<?php $array1=lalala; $array2=lalalal; function attempt($a1,$a2) {...} ?>`

Comment: Everyone always tries `array_merge`, as if it were some magical function that could figure out the relationship that the programmer wants to implement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842272/php-array-merge-two-arrays-on-same-key   ?

Comment: @Xyv That question doesn't involve exploding the elements of one array to merge the values into the other.

Comment: Your edited code doesn't do anything with the variables you set from exploding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explode each value in the Value array. Loop through this and add them to the corresponding element of the User array.

```
foreach ($value_array as $key => $data) {
    $data_array = explode(',', $data);
    foreach ($data_array as $index => $val) {
        $user_array[$index][$key] = $val;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/3bMy9i)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have exploded array for specific keys which need  to be added in main `user_array`. I could not figure out how exactly to use above snippet  to generate expected output. How should I go about it considering above arrays ?

Comment: Just change `$value` for `$value_array` and `$user` to `$user_array`, semantics.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy I've fixed my answer to use your array names.

Comment: Where do you set `$data_array` in your updated code?