# Concatenate strings from 2 array based on key

Tags: php, arrays

so i have a bit difficulty in combining arrays in php. So let say i have these 2 array

```
array:4 [▼
  20 => "University"
  21 => "Polic Station"
  22 => "Ambulance"
  1  => "Zoo"
]

array:4 [▼
  20 => "abc"
  21 => "def"
  22 => "ghi"
  1  => "jkl"
]
```

How do i actually combine this to this

```
array:4 [▼
  20 => "abc University"
  21 => "def Polic Station"
  22 => "ghi Ambulance"
  1  => "jkl Zoo"
]
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842272/php-array-merge-two-arrays-on-same-key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the result:

```
$arr = array(
    20=>'University',
    21=>'Polic Station',
    22=>'Ambulance',
    1=>'Zoo');
$arr2= array(
    20=>'abc',
    21=>'def',
    22=>'ghi',
    1=>'jkl');
$arr_out = array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$el) {
    $arr_out[$key] = $arr2[$key] ." ".$el;
}
var_dump($arr_out);
```

Obviously, you'll need to keep in mind to check whether the key exists in the second array so you do not get an error when accessing the value.

Comment: Works like charm, i will make validation on second array later. Thanks.