# Combine multiple 1-dimensional arrays into one multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Using the following arrays as input:

- style numbers: `Array ( [0] => 1001 [1] => 1002 [2] => 1003 )`
- colors:  `Array ( [0] => 'red' [1] => 'red' [2] => 'red' )`
- small size: `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 )`
- large size: `Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 2 [2] => 2 )`

I need to create an array like this:

```
 array(
    '1001'=>array(
        'color'=>'red',
        'small_size'=>1,
        'large_size'=>2,
    ),
    '1002'=>array(
        'color'=>'red',
        'small_size'=>1,
        'large_size'=>2,
    ),
    '1003'=>array(
        'color'=>'red',
        'small_size'=>1,
        'large_size'=>2,
    )
)
```

Comment: What have you tried ? what problem are you facing?

Comment: Read this stack answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842272/php-array-merge-two-arrays-on-same-key

Comment: `array_merge()`, `array_merge_recursive()` ?

Comment: I have edited this question to clarify the meaning.  Please open this up again, I've dying to drop in a unique answer! @AliveToDie

Comment: @NarotamSaini please do not accept an answer until the question is _unheld_ so that I may submit my answer for your review.

Comment: It seems I'll need to wait for 5 days... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188007/how-long-will-a-question-be-in-on-hold-status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Do it like below (very simple):-***

```
$final_array = array();

foreach($style as $key=>$val){
  $final_array[$val]['color'] = $colors[$key];
  $final_array[$val]['small_size'] = $small_size[$key];
  $final_array[$val]['large_size'] = $large_size[$key];
}

echo "<pre/>";print_r($final_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/776784

***A Better approach to do it***:- https://eval.in/776787

Comment: @mickmackusa  what typo? in your example link everything perfectly fine.

Comment: @mickmackusa  it's not a typo. i just take that name. it's ridiculous . I was thinking that my logic is wrong or some error is coming in my code.

Comment: @mickmackusa  done. check now. I am also not fighting with you. :):):)

Comment: I edited this question a while ago (while it was "on hold") and now that it has gone past the holding time period, I would like to ask you to re-open the question.  The question is clear now.  I assume you have the super-powers necessary to reopen this question.  If you feel it shouldn't be re-opened please leave me a comment explaining why.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this using a `for` loop:

```
$arrayNumbers = array(1001, 1002, 1003);
$arrayColours = array('red', 'red', 'red');
$arraySmallSizes = array(1, 1, 1);
$arrayLargeSizes = array(2, 2, 2);

$output = array();

$count = count($arrayNumbers);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $output[$arrayNumbers[$i]] = array('color' => $arrayColours[$i], 'small_size' => $arraySmallSizes[$i],'large_size' => $arrayLargeSizes[$i]);
}

print_r($output);
// Array (
    [1001] => Array ( [color] => red [small_size] => 1 [large_size] => 2 )  
    [1002] => Array ( [color] => red [small_size] => 1 [large_size] => 2 ) 
    [1003] => Array ( [color] => red [small_size] => 1 [large_size] => 2 )
)
```

(See https://3v4l.org/9Wpj9 for the performance)
Or using a `foreach` loop:

```
$arrayNumbers = array(1001, 1002, 1003);
$arrayColours = array('red', 'red', 'red');
$arraySmallSizes = array(1, 1, 1);
$arrayLargeSizes = array(2, 2, 2);

$output = array();
foreach($arrayNumbers as $key => $value) {
    $output[$arrayNumbers[$key]] = array('color' => $arrayColours[$key], 'small_size' => $arraySmallSizes[$key],'large_size' => $arrayLargeSizes[$key]);
}

print_r($output);
```

(See https://3v4l.org/ifv1o for the performance)

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can try this code i have tested it-

```
$array1 = array( 0 => 1001  , 1 => 1002 ,2 => 1003 );
$array2 = array( 0 => 'red' ,1 => 'red' ,2 => 'red' );
$array3 = array( 0 => 1 ,1 => 1 ,2 => 1 );
$array4 = array( 0 => 2, 1 => 2 ,2 => 2 );
$final_array = [];
foreach($array1 as $key =>$value){
    $final_array[$value]['color'] =   $array2[$key];
    $final_array[$value]['small_size'] =   $array3[$key];
    $final_array[$value]['large_size'] =   $array4[$key];
}
print_r($final_array);
```

Comment: Using a `foreach()` method was posted by AlivetoDie 6 minutes before your answer was posted.  All duplicate answers should be removed because they do not help SO readers and only cause page bloat.  Please practice good SO citizenship and delete this answer.

Answer (score -1):

that code should resolve your problem:

```
$input = array(
    '1001'=>array(
        'color'=>'red',
        'small_size'=>1,
        'large_size'=>2,
    ),
    '1002'=>array(
        'color'=>'red',
        'small_size'=>1,
        'large_size'=>2,
    ),
    '1003'=>array(
        'color'=>'red',
        'small_size'=>1,
        'large_size'=>2,
    ),
);

$keys = array_keys($input);

$color = array_column($input, 'color');
$smallSize = array_column($input, 'small_size');
$largeSize = array_column($input, 'large_size');
```

Comment: You are confused by this poorly worded question.  You are using output as input and providing the input as output.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
 $data = array(
    '1001'=>array(
        'color'=>'red',
        small_size=>1,
        large_size=>2,
    ),
    '1002'=>array(
        'color'=>'red',
        small_size=>1,
        large_size=>2,
    ),
    '1003'=>array(
        'color'=>'red',
        small_size=>1,
        large_size=>2,
    ),
);

var_dump(array_column($data, 'color'));

var_dump(array_column($data, 'small_size'));
```

**Output:**

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "red" [1]=> string(3) "red" [2]=> string(3) "red" } 

array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(1) [2]=> int(1) }
```

Comment: You are confused by this poorly worded question. You are using output as input and providing the input as output.

Comment: What I understood in oq is he is having multi dimension array and he needs selected keys outupt (color, small_size, large_size) in single array.