# Merge two array by key with unique value

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays *(in the foreach loop)* that may or may not have the same dynamically generated keys e.g. `298, 184, 182` as in the code sample below.

I want to merge values for the same keys and make a single array.

> Note: Arrays are the results within the foreach loop.
> Keys are dynamically generated by id and items may or may not be the same in both arrays.

## Resulting Arrays in Loop

```
Array
(
    [298] => Array
        (
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-12-26 10:39:13
                    [1] => 2020-12-15 12:18:23
                    [2] => 2020-12-22 12:27:46
                    [3] => 2020-12-24 10:51:00
                    [4] => 2020-12-26 10:01:44
                    [5] => 2020-12-26 10:31:55
                    [6] => 2020-12-26 10:48:33
                    [7] => 2020-12-26 10:56:34
                )

        )

    [184] => Array
        (
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-11-16 07:52:33
                    [1] => 2020-12-24 13:01:14
                )

        )

    [182] => Array
        (
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2021-01-05 08:50:27
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [298] => Array
        (
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-11-16 07:38:26
                    [1] => 2020-11-16 07:47:05
                    [2] => 2020-12-15 12:20:07
                    [3] => 2020-12-24 10:52:35
                )

        )

    [184] => Array
        (
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-11-16 07:53:12
                )

        )

)
```

## Expecting Single Array

```
Array
(
    [298] => Array
        (
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-12-26 10:39:13
                    [1] => 2020-12-15 12:18:23
                    [2] => 2020-12-22 12:27:46
                    [3] => 2020-12-24 10:51:00
                    [4] => 2020-12-26 10:01:44
                    [5] => 2020-12-26 10:31:55
                    [6] => 2020-12-26 10:48:33
                    [7] => 2020-12-26 10:56:34
                    [8] => 2020-11-16 07:38:26
                    [9] => 2020-11-16 07:47:05
                    [10] => 2020-12-15 12:20:07
                    [11] => 2020-12-24 10:52:35
                )

        )

    [184] => Array
        (
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-11-16 07:52:33
                    [1] => 2020-12-24 13:01:14
                    [2] => 2020-11-16 07:53:12
                )

        )

    [182] => Array
        (
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2021-01-05 08:50:27
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Array Merge two Arrays on same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842272/php-array-merge-two-arrays-on-same-key)

Comment: @UrmatZhenaliev Thanks that's close but Nick's answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the second array can also have keys that are not in the first, you can find all the unique keys from both arrays, and then iterate over them, merging the values from `array1` and `array2` into a result array:

```
$keys = array_unique(array_merge(array_keys($array1), array_keys($array2)));

$result = array();
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $result[$key]['dates'] = array_merge($array1[$key]['dates'] ?? [], $array2[$key]['dates'] ?? []);
}
print_r($result);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Up9E6)

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are a genious. I was trying this for two days with various loops but no luck. I appreciate your help.