# add 1st array value to 2nd array based on key match

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to add 1st array value to 2nd array based on key match but not success with array_merge function see example of what i doing below

```
Array1
(
    [99] => 99
    [98] => 98
    
)
Array2


(
    [99] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1300
            [1] => 1500
            [2] => 1618
            [3] => 2704
            [4] => 1401
            [5] => 1900
            [6] => 1100
            [7] => 4232
            [8] => 4233
        )

    [98] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1400
            [1] => 4802
            [2] => 1601
            [3] => 1603
            [4] => 1100
            [5] => 1900
        )
    )
```

> my code so far returning me wrong output like this

```
$finalArray = array_merge($Array1, $Array2);
```

> what i am expecting

```
finalArray
(
    
   [99] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1300
            [1] => 1500
            [2] => 1618
            [3] => 2704
            [4] => 1401
            [5] => 1900
            [6] => 1100
            [7] => 4232
            [8] => 4233
            [9] => 99
        )

    [98] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1400
            [1] => 4802
            [2] => 1601
            [3] => 1603
            [4] => 1100
            [5] => 1900
            [6] => 98
        )
    )
```

i have tried array_merge, array_push & array combine as well but not success
please somebody help me on this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Array Merge two Arrays on same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842272/php-array-merge-two-arrays-on-same-key)

Comment: @uzthegeek There are tons of duplicates already for this. Did you follow those approaches?

Comment: @nice_dev i have tried they are single array my array is multidimensional that's why failed

Comment: Just loop over your first array, and then add the value under the same key in the second ... `foreach($array1 as $key => $value) { $array2[$key][] = $value; }`

Comment: @CBroe i did but not working ;(

Comment: Show a proper example of what exactly you tried then please. (Edit the question.)

Comment: @CBroe i have showed proper example in simple words i want to add array1 value into array2 values based on both array key match that is simple !!!

Comment: _"i have showed proper example"_ - not of your attempt to implement my suggestion. How are we supposed to tell you what you did _wrong_, when you don't show us what exactly you did? I can only assume that you simply did not pay enough attention to make the variables names match yours, because other than that, my suggestion works the same as the answer you now accepted. https://3v4l.org/CjkTd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the work for you

[Example code](https://onlinephp.io/c/074d1)

```
   <?php
    $arr1 = Array
    (
        '99' => 99,
        '98' => 98
        
    );

    $arr2 = Array(
        '99' => Array
            (
                '0' => 1300,
                '1' => 1500,
                '2' => 1618,
                '3' => 2704,
                '4' => 1401,
                '5' => 1900,
                '6' => 1100,
                '7' => 4232,
                '8' => 4233
            ),
        '98' => Array
            (
                '0' => 1400,
                '1' => 4802,
                '2' => 1601,
                '3' => 1603,
                '4' => 1100,
                '5' => 1900
            )
        );
        
     foreach($arr1 as $key => $value){
      if(isset($arr2[$key])){
        array_push($arr2[$key],$value);
      }else{
        $arr2[$key] = $value;
      }
    }
        
        print_r($arr2);
```